# In a Foundry Code Repository, how do I log debug messages from within a Python transform?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Is there any way to introduce debugging statements in your Transforms code, so you can later see them in driver logs, for example? Or is raising exceptions the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible as of transforms-python 1.9.0 driver logs get written to the transaction. You can use [python logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to write logs.
For example:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_transform(input):
    log.info("Testing logging")
    return input
```

Comment: Would it be possible to log not on the __name__ logger, but with a diffrent handler / file, in order not to have logging messages merged on the standard driver log?